# What version of ios is required for apps created with flash cs5.5?

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I was wondering what is the minimal version of ios required to use the applications i create for ios with flash cs5.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Adobe AIR 3 tech specs (https://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html) the minimum version of iOS required is iOS 4 (you can also see the hardware requirements there).